# ImageView re-size while setting Image after Cropping

Tags: android, resize, imageview, scale, crop

I follow this http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html to crop image.

I have 4-5 ImageView in a collage frame.In All Imageview i have set a default image.On click on particular imageview, I am selecting Image from gallery then crop the Image. Now I have to set the cropped Image in my ImageView. So after setting the cropped Image my ImageView get re-size, and because of it other ImageView's size also differ. I want while i am setting the cropped image in Imageview my ImageView must not re-size.

The size of resulted cropped Image may different so I took the ImageView Size before cropping, And after cropping I am scaling result bitmap as the same size of my Image view.

Coding sample is given blow.

I am getting height and width of my Imageview like this

```
  viewhight = tempView.getMeasuredHeight();
    viewWidth = tempView.getMeasuredWidth();
```

After cropping Image I scaled Image according to height and width of my view like this

```
Bitmap photobitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photobitmap, viewWidth,viewhight, true);
```

After this i changed it into drawable like this and set it on my Imageview.

```
 Drawable drawble = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),photobitmap1);
tempView.setBackground(drawble);
```

but on setting the hight and width of my view get resized and because of this near Image view also get resized why I don't know.because i converted my imageview in the same size of view.

I also tried this to scale bitmap :

```
Bitmap photobitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photobitmap, (viewWidth-30), (viewhight-30), true);
```

and this to set bitmap :

```
tempView.setImageBitmap(photobitmap1);
 tempView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but nothing worked.

my xml code is like this:

```
   <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fst"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/frame"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="85dp"
                android:paddingRight="85dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
               >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/viw_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rec"
                 />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/viw_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rec"
                 />
            </LinearLayout>
```

can any one help me please .....

Comment: I cant understand what you've written, you should be loading the image  to fit the ImageView, not the other way round.

Comment: please check I have Edited question's explanation .

Comment: it is same like we use the image from drawable folder and it takes size default but if we get from drawanle-nodpi than it take same size for all device same here while you resize your bitmap and set than your weight is also scaled the view too so set the either fix size dimen to both of your frame or set please set the scale type to both  the imageview(frame)

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting a fixed height and width for the imageview in the XML ?
Example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layoutWidth="60dp"
    android:layoutHeight="60dp" />
```

Comment: No, I used wrapcontent and match_parent. I took the layout_weight also. so using like this -  android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: If your using the wrap_content as the width the imageview will resize, you need to set a fixed width like the above code suggests.

Comment: the wrap content will adjust the size of the imageview based on the image. Specify a fixed size for the image, then the issue will be fixed

Comment: I can't use fix size because it will not work for all device resolution.

Comment: if you use 'dp' to specify the size, it will look the same in all devices